# Error when searching for title and price at the same time

Tags: python, django

I have got a filter form, where I can filter the content by category, title and the price. I am able to search the items by the category and price or category and title at the same time, but I am getting an error when I am trying to filter by using price and the title.

Here's the error, that I am getting after filtering by price and the title:

```
FieldError at /

 Cannot resolve keyword 'current_price' into field. Choices are: category, description, discount_price, id, image, label, orderitem, price, slug, title
```

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  item_list = item_list.annotate(current_price=Coalesce('discount_price', 'price'))

  category_list = Category.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')

  if query:
      item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

  cat = request.GET.get('cat')
  if cat:
      item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=cat)

  price_from = request.GET.get('price_from')
  price_to = request.GET.get('price_to')

  if price_from:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__gte=price_from)

  if price_to:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__lte=price_to)

  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'items': items,
      'category': category_list
  }
  return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

html:

```
        <form method="GET" action=".">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select id="cat" class="form-control" name="cat">
                <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="" href="/home">All</option>
                {% for cat in category %}
                <option value="{{ cat.pk }}">{{ cat }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Brand..">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_from"
                placeholder="Price from">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_to"
                placeholder="Price to">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is probably being caused by

```
if query:
       item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
```

where you are overwriting the `item_list` that had the `current_price` annotation.

Try filtering `item_list` instead of `Item.objects`.

Comment: That was it, thank you for your help. I have got one more question, when I put data in my form and press search i got the results, but the form is empty, is there a way to keep the form filled with the data from the search?

Comment: Glad that helped. I recommend that you ask about the empty form as a separate question so that more people can see it to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check you Item model.
The error message is saying you than there is no current_price in the Item model. As you didn't putted the Item class and according to error message maybe you want to search in 'price':

```
if price_from:
    item_list =item_list.filter(price__gte=price_from)

if price_to:
    item_list = item_list.filter(price__lte=price_to)
```